# PHP, Running script in windows Command line not working

Tags: php, windows, command

When I run my script like this:

```
c:\path\to\php.exe -f "c:\script.php"
```

It "echos" the code in the dos window but does not execute it.

Any ideas why? All I have in script.php is :

```
<?PHP


//code and stuff

?>
```

*I'm also using javascript/jquery in this script. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language that requires a server to use. The latest version of PHP includes a built in development server so that you can learn to write php. It is not too hard to set setup, however , I recommend Wamp server if you are interested in learning PHP or web development in general. It is easy to setup and comes with php and mysql so you can use wordpress and other content management systems.

Comment: Dude, I know.  I'm not asking how to setup a php server etc etc.